# associative array not setting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp-classic, associative-array

i'm new to javascript and jquery and was wondering if someone could let me in on why this isn't working correctly.

i have a drop-down box that a user selects a value from, then "Processes." When processed the value of the drop-down as well as a textbox is stored in an array.  I want the user to be able to then basically store the same drop-down selection and textbox data in the array again but now in a new value pair.

First store would be
TestArray[0][0] = "Textbox Value"

If "Processed" again, it would be 
TestArray[1][0] = "Textbox Value"

that way I can parse through later and figure how many times the user "Processed" the drop-down selection;

```
var oneClickReport = $("#reportName").val();
    if(oneClickReport == "Sample Report One"){
        var arrayOneCount = reportOneArray.length;
        var totalHouseholds = 0;
            $("#reportChecks span:visible").each(function(){            
                if($(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked')){
                    var HHName = $(this).text();
                    reportOneArray.push(HHName);
                    arrayTest[arrayOneCount][totalHouseholds] = HHName;
                }
            totalHouseholds += 1;
            });
            for(i = 0; i < arrayOneCount; i+=1){
                alert(arrayTest[0][i]);
            }
    }
```

But when trying to "Process" for the second time, I receive the error of;

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property '0' of undefined or null reference
```

on line;

```
arrayTest[arrayOneCount][totalHouseholds] = HHName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array. I'm not sure what exactly you want to do but you need an array like this

```
var arrayTest = []
```

And you will need to initialize subsequent value like

```
arrayTest[1] = []
```

Then you can access your array

```
arrayTest[1][0] = []
```

I made an example for you

```
var oneClickReport = $("#reportName").val();
var arrayTest = [] # You may need to put this elsewhere
if(oneClickReport == "Sample Report One"){
    var arrayOneCount = reportOneArray.length;
    var totalHouseholds = 0;
        $("#reportChecks span:visible").each(function(){            
            if($(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked')){
                var HHName = $(this).text();
                reportOneArray.push(HHName);

                if(!arrayTest[arrayOneCount]){ arrayTest[arrayOneCount] = []; }

                arrayTest[arrayOneCount][totalHouseholds] = HHName;
            }
        totalHouseholds += 1;
        });
        for(i = 0; i < arrayOneCount; i+=1){
            alert(arrayTest[0][i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think i've almost got it.  One thing I ran into that I definitely wasn't thinking about is that if the user initially selects more than 1 checkbox to be added, the arrayOneCount value will not be 1, but however many was selected.  is there a way for me to just check if the arrayTest[0] or arrayTest[1] etc. has been initialized and populated?  I really just want something like if the user process "Report One" first time it's stored in arrayTest[0] for all selected checkboxes, then if they process again arrayTest[1] etc.   Thanks again

Comment: You can acheive this with the length property of the array.



if(arrayTest[arrayOneCount].length > 0){
   #There is something in the arrayTest[arrayOneCount]
}
else{
   #There is nothing in the arrayTest[arrayOneCount]
}

Answer (score 0):

your problem with `var arrayOneCount = reportOneArray.length;` and you're not changing this value

Comment: the value will be incremented everytime the function is called.  It will re-count the new values that were added to the array and update that way